# .insert() self-classification issue

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, insert

.insert() function shows a non expected result.

In the present piece of code we try to rewrite a vector (b) which includes two equal values in different index, just in the same previous form.

```
a = []
b = [*range(1, 11, 1)]
b.insert(1,6)
for c in b:
    a.append(c)
    a.remove(c)
    a.insert(c-1,c)
print("b = ",b)
print ("a = ",a)
```

However, the repeated value is replaced at the end of the vector, changing the index of the next values sorted previously, as it is shown:

```
b =  [1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6]
```

I couldn't find a reason why it is happening or, at least, how to solve it making as less changes as posible in the main code.

Comment: Can you explain what you intended to get for this particular input? What is the purpose of this code? What if `b=[100, 200, 300, 200]`? What should happen then?

Comment: The purpose is to take some values from a software output to use it as input for another software (with different output-input structure), but data must be classified in a specific vector. We observed that this error produces a deviation in the input data, producing a non expected result. However, whith the vector that you provide there is no self-sorting and I will apreciate if you tell me the reason, it may help us to solve the problem.

Comment: You mention "unexpected result", but I have no idea what you expect. Can you describe what exactly you expect in simple terms? It would be nice to provide some more examples. What is the *expected* output for `b=[100, 200, 300, 200]` or for `b=[100, -200, 300, -200]`? What is the "classification" you mention? That is a rather vague term. What is it to be classified *by*?

Comment: the expected result is that the vector "a" will have the same order of values than vector "b", why does it change? I look for the same result for "a" and "b" vectors. Sorry If I did not state it clearly. With classification I mean extract values one by one from a .txt output and write it into a vector for a specific variable.

Comment: And why do you insert 6 into `b`? Your code is modifying both `a` and `b`, so I am confused what you mean with "I look for the same result for "a" and "b". Is there a reason why you insert 6 in into `b`? Sorry I don't understand all this. Can't you just simplify the question and include 5 different examples of input, and the corresponding output you expect? In the last comment you mention an output file and writing. Is that really essential to your question? I don't see how it is relevant.

Comment: With the previous input I try to understand why when you introduce the values of one 0 to 10 vector with two equal values (in this case two "6" values), "b", to another empty, "a", one of the equal values is replaced at the end of the vector changing the index of the rest of the values in the new "a" vector. futhermore, I would like to know why it is not happening with a vector such as 'b=[100, 100, 200, 300, 200]'.

Comment: e.g. input `a=[] b=[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, Output of the previous piece of code: `b=[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`

Comment: As to "why?" I don't understand why you expect anything else. Just use a debugger and step through the code one statement at a time and inspect variables. Is there anything you find that doesn't work as expected? What makes you think this code should have produced different output? At which iteration and which statement do you think the code does not what it is supposed to do?

Comment: After doing some cases I think I understand the mechanism of the .insert() function and de piece of code that I posted. The .insert() function there try to insert both 6s of the "b" vector at the same index in "a" causing one of them go through the vector without an specific index to the end, right?. In that case, the output was logical, as you tried to say. Thanks you so much for your help.